# Dropdown won't accept defaultValue change

Tags: semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

https://codesandbox.io/s/pQoyXymr2
Here's the demo. It seems Dropdown only receive defaultValue once, and not changing after, why?

Answer (score 1):

`defaultValue` will affect only initial component `value`, so need to use the `value` prop to control Dropdown's value. This follows React's patterns with [uncontrolled](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/uncontrolled-components.html) and [controlled](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) components.